# Using ROS with Docker - Unable to set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: docker, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm setting up a docker container for a project of mine which runs using ROS. I'm using rosmake and need to set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable to include my own packages before calling rosmake.
In the Dockerfile, I use
ENV ROS_PACKAGE_PATH /foo:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

However when I run the container, the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH only contains /opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
I need some help with this because without setting the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH I can't invoke a rosmake from inside the Dockerfile.
Since the exact same method of setting environment variables is being used, successfully to set other non-ROS-related variables, I feel it might be more of a ROS issue than a Docker issue.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237133/using-ros-with-docker---unable-to-set-ros_package_path/) by [AkshatAgarwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/21134/akshatagarwal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that the Dockerfile set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH env variable for build time but it got reset during run time. I solved this by putting a script that set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH inside the container and calling it in the dockerfile using a RUN command before running rosmake through the Dockerfile itself. That worked beautifully.

---

Originally posted by [AkshatAgarwal](https://answers.ros.org/users/21134/akshatagarwal/) with karma: 31 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0